# Twilio SIP directly to phone

Tags: twilio, sip, sip-server, twilio-php

I have an IP phone but not a SIP Registry. Is it possible for me to set up my IP phone directly with Twilio SIP without having to depend on OpenPBX or FreePBX, just Twilio directly to my IP phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Megan from Twilio.

At this time you need [a PBX](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/sample-configuration) to connect IP phones to our service. With that set up you would be able to [send](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/sending-sip-how-it-works) and [receive](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/receiving-sip-how-it-works) SIP via Twilio.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Has this changed? It seems now it is possible right?

Comment: @FabricioG I don't believe it's possible to register a SIP endpoint within the Twilio Console still, but you can totally use a softphone that will register with the SIP domain directly. I've had good experience with [Bria Solo](https://www.counterpath.com/bria-solo/).

Comment: @NReilingh I actually ended up doing it.  The SIP phone has to be setup with the sam settings you would put on the soft phone.